# How to show that $e^x$ can be approximated by the polynomial $P_{(4)} (x) $to within 0.025 for all values of x on the interval [−1,1]?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

How to show that $e^x$ can be approximated by the Taylor polynomial  $P_{(4)} (x)$  within $0.025$ on the interval $[−1,1]$?

What is the logic of this question? Should I use Taylor's formula and find a remainder $R$ such $R< 0.025$, and then show that the last term in $P_{(4)} (x)$ which is $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ is greater than $R$?

Comment: There is a formula that tells you the error when you truncate the Taylor series to a particular order. In your case it's a polynomial with degree 5. Also, you must use $e^x<3$ if $x<1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder See the Lagrange form of the remainder

Comment: @Andrei So is the framework of the solution that I presented incorrect?